# How to analyze image quality?

Tags: image-processing, distortion, motion

I have a few sequences of images, taken at fixed camera position, that address a moving object, which means the object moves towards the camera. But all the sequences of images are the cropped images of the object and all images are in the **same size (grayscale images)**. ***From naked eyes, we can see the images that are closer to the camera are  better than the ones that taken at far distance.*** How can I show scientifically or show a proof that the images have varied quality? I also want to compare the quality between  sequences.

Comment: SE.DSP wishes you a happy new year 2017, with a kind reminder that your question and its answers may require some action (update, votes, acceptance, etc.)

Comment: http://jbthomas.org/SupervisedPhD/2015PingZhaoThesis.pdf
Camera based Display Image Quality
Assessment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apparently in the context of **no-reference**, **reference-free** or **blind image quality assessment**. The topic is quite active, and I am not sure people have already a completely accepted framework for that. Multiple distortions may affect images: random noise, compression artifact, static blur, motion blur, etc. They require different metrics ([benchmark data here](http://live.ece.utexas.edu/research/quality/index.htm)). Some references to start with, and help you for more focused questions:

- [No-Reference Image Quality Assessment in the Spatial Domain](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2012.2214050), 2012
- [Making a “Completely Blind” Image Quality Analyzer](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/LSP.2012.2227726), 2013
- [No-reference image quality assessment based on spatial and spectral entropies](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.image.2014.06.006), 2014
- [MDID: A multiply distorted image database for image quality assessment](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.patcog.2016.07.033), 2017

The first three papers come from the same group, an hint that the paint is still wet.